# How to convert a unix time to GMT+8 human readable date without FROM_UNIXTIME() function?

Tags: mysql, timezone, unix-timestamp, autogeneratecolumn

Since mysql `Generated Column` can't use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` as generate sql, how can I convert a unix time to GMT+8 human readable date? My failed example:

```
    ALTER TABLE just_a_table
    ADD COLUMN created_date
    CHAR(5) 
    GENERATED ALWAYS 
        AS (FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at, "%m/%d")) 
        STORED;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since mysql `Generated Column` can't use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` as generate sql

???

`FROM_UNIXTIME()` is deterministic function. It can be used in generated column expression easily.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE just_a_table (created_at BIGINT);
> INSERT INTO just_a_table VALUES 
> (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)),
> (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY));
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE just_a_table
> ADD COLUMN created_date CHAR(5) 
>     GENERATED ALWAYS AS (FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at, "%m/%d")) STORED;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM just_a_table
> ```
>
> ```
> created_at | created_date
> ---------: | :-----------
> 1619167553 | 04/23       
> 1618998353 | 04/21
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5b7610d8c18d4f37bec780279667bb70)*

Comment: I think is mysql version issue, my production env version did not allow me to do so, the error msg: `Function or expression 'from_unixtime()' cannot be used in the GENERATED ALWAYS`

Comment: @DaveICS Can you at least now tell us what version of MySQL server you have?

Comment: it's `10.4.17-MariaDB`

Comment: @DaveICS https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/#expression-support *Most built-in functions are supported in expressions for generated columns.
However, some built-in functions can't be supported for technical reasons.* You're just out of luck. Think, maybe VIRTUAL column is safe for you? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=20c6595282731f934da0c03bb7819fac PS. Remember - MariaDB is NOT MySQL!!! Yes, it is highly compatible, but no more.